# Regular expression for remove everything except 10 number?

Tags: javascript, regex

I learn right now regular expression and need to know, how I can remove all except 10 numbers or maximum 10 number, I tried to create RegExp like this

```
var value = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
```

Comment: Please give examples which demonstrate what your regex is supposed to be doing.  It isn't' clear to me whether by `10 numbers` you mean the number 10, or a list of 10 numbers.

Comment: Can you give me an example, I couldn't understand your question

Comment: @Sebastian, are you looking for something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QMPwxV

Comment: Remember that "removing all except x" is the same as "keeping x".

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If user wanna enter more than 10 numbers i wanna to replace it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex's `{0,10}` range of times to specify the length of the number.

My example will produce to matches,

```
[
  "1348737734",
  "8775"
]
```

It will match first number with the length of 10, and the rest of the number.

```js
const str = 'asb13487377348775nvnn';
const result = str.match(/(\d{1,10})/g);
console.log(result);
```